# SQL Sum Function limit 0, 3 returning sum of entire column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

Good afternoon,

I'm looking to find the sum of the total column in the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `btb_picks` 
WHERE  `player_name` =  'bryan'
ORDER BY  `total` 
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

The table has a total of 9 records where player_name='bryan'

```
Position Golfer Name    Round 1 Round 2 Round 3 Round 4 Today   Through Total   Player Name
T4       Lee Westwood   67      12:25   -       -       -5      F       -5      bryan
T4       Justin Rose    67      1:39    -       -       -5      F       -5      bryan
T4       Sergio Garcia  67      1:49    -       -       -5      F       -5      bryan
```

I would like to gather the sum of the total (-15) of these 3 records

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT SUM( total ) AS 3_man
FROM  `btb_picks` 
WHERE  `player_name` =  'bryan'
ORDER BY total
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

It returns:

3_man
-13

Which is the sum of the entire total column not the 3 records I'm interested in finding the total for.

When I try the query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `btb_picks` WHERE `player_name` in ( SELECT * 
    FROM  `btb_picks` 
    WHERE  `player_name` =  'bryan'
    ORDER BY  `total` 
    LIMIT 0 , 3 );
```

SQL barks:

1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

How can I get the sum of total in these three records?

Comment: ORDER BY  `total` desc if your record current 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT SUM(s.score) FROM
(SELECT total as score FROM btb_picks WHERE player_name = 'bryan' ORDER BY total LIMIT 0,3) s
```